# Can't paginate in livewire component

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to paginate items in a livewire component, I have this query

```
protected $listeners = [
  'franchises:coords' => 'getFranchises'
];

public $franchiseList;

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.franchise-list', ['franchiseList' => $this->franchiseList]);
}

public function getFranchises($coords)
{
    if ($coords) {
        $latitude = json_decode($coords)[0];
        $longitude = json_decode($coords)[1];
        $radiusInMeters = 800;

        $this->franchiseList = Franchise::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6371000 * acos( cos( radians(' . $latitude . ') )
        * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $longitude . ') )
        + sin( radians(' . $latitude . ') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
            ->having('distance', '<', $radiusInMeters)
            ->orderBy('distance')
            ->paginate(8);
    }
}
```

the component is included in my "maps.blade"

```
            <div class="lg:basis-1/4 md:basis-1/4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <livewire:franchise-list/>
            </div>
```

and in my blade view, I have this

```
            @if(!empty($franchiseList))
                {{$franchiseList->links()}}
            @endif
```

but I get this error

> Livewire component's [franchise-list] public property [franchiseList]
> must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only
> protected or private properties can be set as other types because
> JavaScript doesn't need to access them.

If I try to change pagination by adding these lines to the `getFranchises` function and adding `$links` to public

```
public $franchiseList, $links;

        //after paginate
        $this->links = $this->franchiseList;
        $this->franchiseList = collect($this->franchiseList->items);
```

and in the blade change to this

```
            @if(!empty($franchiseList) && $links->links())
                {{$links->links()}}
            @endif
```

I get this error

> Error Cannot access protected property
> Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$items

How can I paginate in livewire? where is the problem?

Comment: how or where did you initialize the property? I mean, to be binded to blade component

Comment: ok, it's a nested component but don't see where you init the $this->franchiseList property. Don't you have a mount function where to init it like $this->franchiseList = Collection::empty(); ??? // or []

Comment: @Prospero I understand that it is not necessary if they are already started in public $franchiseList, $links;    anyway I added mount () function and the result is the same.....         $this->franchiseList = [];
        $this->links = [];

Comment: can you post your current render function??? also, the correct sintax in blade is $franchiseList->links(), u don't need $this->links property

Comment: @Prospero I updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I guess your issue is right there in render method. Instead of doing what you're doing, change this once you have in the mount the property initialized

```
public $franchiseList;

public function mount()
{
   $this->franchiseList = [];
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.franchise-list');
}
```

So, as the property is public you can bind it in blade directly. At load component, it is an empty array and on event (in listener) this will change to passed value. That's the idea, but if you do this ['franchiseList' => $this->franchiseList] it's going to be crashed (when same name). I can't tell you why because I really don't know the answer but I know this happens from my experience.